# Can Kotlin allow a function that returns a value of this interface's implementation's type?

Tags: interface, kotlin

I want to write something like this:

```kotlin
/**
 * Represents a state, large or small.
 */
interface State {
    /**
     * 
     */
    val changeValue: StateChange<This> // does not compile; "This" is a keyword I made up that might reference the implementing class
}


/**
 * Represents a change in a state, large or small.
 *
 * @param StateType The type of state that has changed
 */
interface StateChange<StateType: State>
```

However, as noted in my comment, I don't know the syntax for this. Is that in existance? Or must I use workarounds like forcing a State to take in itself as a generic parameter?

---

In case it's not apparent, I can't use `val changeValue: StateChange<State>` because then that makes this possible, and I don't want that:

```
// BAD EXAMPLE - This is what I want to avoid
class Foo: State { val changeValue: StateChange<Bar> = Bar().changeValue }
class Bar: State { val changeValue: StateChange<Foo> = Foo().changeValue }
```

Comment: `Bar().changeValue` is of type `StateChange<Foo>` and you're trying to assign it to `StateChange<Bar>`. What would that mean even if it worked?

Comment: @miensol I have no idea. That's why I want to avoid making that possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a class with a recursive upper bound for this:

```
interface State<T : State<T>> {
    val changeValue: StateChange<T>
}

interface StateChange<StateType: State<StateType>>
```

Now this code will no longer compile:

```
class Foo: State<Foo> { val changeValue: StateChange<Bar> = Bar().changeValue }
class Bar: State<Bar> { val changeValue: StateChange<Foo> = Foo().changeValue }
```

Comment: So I must "use workarounds like forcing a State to take in itself as a generic parameter"? Aww man

Comment: Well, yes. The concept of "self type" is relatively uncommon in programming languages and, as far as I understand, it interacts quite badly with Java's type system in interop scenarios.